# Git commit message validation

Tags: git, commit

My commit message will be in the following format:

```
ANDROID-123 #commit Your commit message
```

`ANDROID-` is fixed keyword.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Use a git-hook? https://githooks.com/

Answer (score 2):

Git hooks are scripts that run automatically at certain stages of your git workflow. There is a `commit-msg` git hook for the purpose of checking or changing commit messages during the commit process. See the [git scm documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gitlabhook, for example a pre-receive hook where you will defined a regex for your commit message , and then check if the new commit message is like your predefined regex. 
its gonna be something like this:

```
REGEX="Your regex"

while read oldrev newrev refname ; do
#Validate commit message format
  for COMMIT in `git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev`;
  do
    MESSAGE=`git cat-file commit $COMMIT | sed '1,/^$/d'`       
    if [[ $MESSAGE =~ $REGEX ]]; then
      echo ""
    else 
      echo -e "Error Message" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
  done
```